# SQL IN Operator Selection ORDER?

Tags: mysql, sql

For the SQL IN Operator

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');
```

If it is going to select the rows with all values matched first? I do realize that the query can be translated into

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country = Germany OR Country = France OR Country = UK;
```

But let's say I have this table

```
[id   -   customer   -   Country]
[ 1   -     CUS1     -   Germany]
[ 2   -     CUS1     -   UK     ]
[ 3   -     CUS2     -   UK     ]
[ 4   -     CUS3     -   Germany]
[ 5   -     CUS1     -   France ]
[ 6   -     CUS3     -   UK     ]
[ 7   -     CUS2     -   France ]
[ 8   -     CUS2     -   Germany]
```

The statics would be

```
CUS1 = [Germany, UK, France];
CUS2 = [UK, France, Germany];
CUS3 = [Germany, UK];
```

For `IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK');` What i expect to get is `[CUS1, CUS2, CUS3];`

But for `IN ('Germany', 'UK');` What i expect to get is `[CUS3, CUS1, CU2];`

But I still keep getting `[CUS1, CUS2, CUS3];`

What I'm trying to do is get the very matched values first, so if I have `IN ('Germany', 'UK');` I get `CUS3` first because it has the exact number and countries then `CUS1` because its first two countries are the exact same too, But with extra country, `CUS2` At last because the matched countries are reversed with extra country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the number of matches, then a single `IN` is not sufficient.  You need to combine data from multiple rows -- and that suggests aggregation.

You can get the customers by doing:

```
SELECT c.customer
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK')
GROUP BY c.customer
ORDER BY COUNT(c.County) DESC;
```

(Note:  If you can can have duplicates, then use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in the `HAVING` clause.)

If you need the original rows, then use `IN`, `EXISTS`, or `JOIN` to get them.